# Create diagonal matrix from rows of a 2D matrix without for loop

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray, diagonal

Suppose that you have a `mxn` matrix A and want to create m diagonal matrices, each of which is from rows of A and thus has the shape `nxn`. The resulting matrix should have the shape `mxnxn`.

I know a typical solution would be:

```
result = numpy.stack([numpy.diag(A[i,:]) for i in range(A.shape[0])], axis=0)
```

I am wondering if it is possible we can get the same result without using a loop.

Any idea would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
result = np.zeros((A.shape[0], A.shape[1], A.shape[1]), dtype=A.dtype)
result[:, range(A.shape[1]), range(A.shape[1])] = A
```

**Test input:**

```
A = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)
```

**Output of `print(result)`:**

```
[[[ 0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  1  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  2  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  3  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  4  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  5]]

 [[ 6  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  7  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  8  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  9  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0 10  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0 11]]

 [[12  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0 13  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0 14  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 15  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0 16  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0 17]]

 [[18  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0 19  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0 20  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 21  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0 22  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0 23]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not going to be the most efficient way of doing it but something like this might work

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(10, 5)

S = np.einsum("ai,ij->aij", A, np.ones((5, 5)))
M = np.eye(5).astype(np.bool)
M = np.repeat(M[None, ...], 10, axis=0)
S[~M]=0
print(S.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following where we use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [`numpy.identity()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html) to obtain the desired result.

```
# `arr` is input of size (m, n); for instance,
arr = np.arange(1, 13).reshape(3, -1)   # (3, 4)

# get column size
In [160]: _ , n = arr.shape

# fill the rows from the input, after promoting it to 3D
In [161]: res = np.eye(n, dtype=arr.dtype) * arr[:,np.newaxis]

In [162]: res.shape
Out[162]: (3, 4, 4)
```

---

Note: since we'll have `(n,n)` as last two dimensions, [np.identity()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.identity.html) would also work.

```
In [171]: res = np.identity(n, dtype=arr.dtype) * arr[:,np.newaxis]

In [172]: res.shape
Out[172]: (3, 4, 4)
```

---

Another approach would be to use [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) where first initialize the result array with zeros and slice out the indices of the diagonal elements and populate them with the input array.

Answer (score 0):

*(Found my way here, because I happened to run into something requiring dealing with the Jacobian/partial derivatives of the Softmax activation function lately)*

Inspired by the above answer by @Ananda :

Here's a way to do it using  numpy.einsum **in one line**

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)       # set the seed for a reproducible result
A = np.random.rand(2,3) # MxN for M = 2, N =3
result = np.einsum('ij,jk->ijk', A, np.eye(A.shape[1]))

print(f'{A=}\n{result=}\n')
print('The outputs shape:', result.shape)
```

and the output will be

```
A=array([[0.5488135 , 0.71518937, 0.60276338],
   [0.54488318, 0.4236548 , 0.64589411]])
result=array([[[0.5488135 , 0.        , 0.        ],
    [0.        , 0.71518937, 0.        ],
    [0.        , 0.        , 0.60276338]],

   [[0.54488318, 0.        , 0.        ],
    [0.        , 0.4236548 , 0.        ],
    [0.        , 0.        , 0.64589411]]])

The output shape: (2, 3, 3)
```